# How to show current date in a Listview with custom calendar

Tags: java, android

I follow tutorials [1](http://ashutoshkumarojha.wordpress.com/2013/05/23/custom-calendar-in-android/) and [2](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34) this tutorial in order to get horizontal listview view using custom `HorizontalListView` class. Below is my code. Everything works fine, but the problem is that when the application starts, it shows dates from 1, not from current date.

What can I do?

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQwHQ.jpg) is my snapshot

```
public class MyCalendarActivity extends Activity implements  
    OnClickListener  {
private static final String tag = "MyCalendarActivity";

private TextView currentMonth;
private Button selectedDayMonthYearButton;
private ImageView prevMonth;
private ImageView nextMonth;
private HorizontalListView  calendarView;
private GridCellAdapter adapter;
private Calendar _calendar;
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private int month, year;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi" })
private final DateFormat dateFormatter = new DateFormat();
private static final String dateTemplate = "MMMM yyyy";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_calendar_view);

    _calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    month = _calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    year = _calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    Log.d(tag, "Calendar Instance:= " + "Month: " + month + " " + "Year: "
            + year);

    selectedDayMonthYearButton = (Button) this
            .findViewById(R.id.selectedDayMonthYear);
    selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: ");

    prevMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.prevMonth);
    prevMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

    currentMonth = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.currentMonth);
    currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate,
            _calendar.getTime()));

    nextMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.nextMonth);
    nextMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

//  HorizontalListView listview = (HorizontalListView) 
    findViewById(R.id.listview);  

    calendarView = (HorizontalListView) this.findViewById(R.id.calendar);

    // Initialised
    adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

/**
 * 
 * @param month
 * @param year
 */
private void setGridCellAdapterToDate(int month, int year) {
    adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
    _calendar.set(year, month - 1, _calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate,
            _calendar.getTime()));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == prevMonth) {
        if (month <= 1) {
            month = 12;
            year--;
        } else {
            month--;
        }
        Log.d(tag, "Setting Prev Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: "
                + month + " Year: " + year);
        setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
    }
    if (v == nextMonth) {
        if (month > 11) {
            month = 1;
            year++;
        } else {
            month++;
        }
        Log.d(tag, "Setting Next Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: "
                + month + " Year: " + year);
        setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
    }

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(tag, "Destroying View ...");
    super.onDestroy();
}

// Inner Class
public class GridCellAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
    private static final String tag = "GridCellAdapter";
    private final Context _context;

    private final List<String> list;
    private static final int DAY_OFFSET = 1;
    private final String[] weekdays = new String[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue",
            "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
    private final String[] months = { "January", "February", "March",
            "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
            "October", "November", "December" };
    private final int[] daysOfMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30,
            31, 30, 31 };
    private int daysInMonth;
    private int currentDayOfMonth;
    private int currentWeekDay;
    private Button gridcell;
    private TextView num_events_per_day;
    private final HashMap<String, Integer> eventsPerMonthMap;
    private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "dd-MMM-yyyy");

    // Days in Current Month
    public GridCellAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            int month, int year) {
        super();
        this._context = context;
        this.list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Log.d(tag, "==> Passed in Date FOR Month: " + month + " "
                + "Year: " + year);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        setCurrentDayOfMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        setCurrentWeekDay(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
        Log.d(tag, "New Calendar:= " + calendar.getTime().toString());
        Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfWeek :" + getCurrentWeekDay());
        Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfMonth :" + getCurrentDayOfMonth());

        // Print Month
        printMonth(month, year);

        // Find Number of Events
        eventsPerMonthMap = findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(year, month);
    }

    private String getMonthAsString(int i) {
        return months[i];
    }

    private String getWeekDayAsString(int i) {
        return weekdays[i];
    }

    private int getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(int i) {
        return daysOfMonth[i];
    }

    public String getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    /**
     * Prints Month
     * 
     * @param mm
     * @param yy
     */
    private void printMonth(int mm, int yy) {
        Log.d(tag, "==> printMonth: mm: " + mm + " " + "yy: " + yy);
        int trailingSpaces = 0;
        int daysInPrevMonth = 0;
        int prevMonth = 0;
        int prevYear = 0;
        int nextMonth = 0;
        int nextYear = 0;

        int currentMonth = mm - 1;
        String currentMonthName = getMonthAsString(currentMonth);
        daysInMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(currentMonth);

        Log.d(tag, "Current Month: " + " " + currentMonthName + " having "
                + daysInMonth + " days.");


        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(yy, currentMonth, 1);
        Log.d(tag, "Gregorian Calendar:= " + cal.getTime().toString());

        if (currentMonth == 11) {
            prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
            daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
            nextMonth = 0;
            prevYear = yy;
            nextYear = yy + 1;
            Log.d(tag, "*->PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                    + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                    + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
        } else if (currentMonth == 0) {
            prevMonth = 11;
            prevYear = yy - 1;
            nextYear = yy;
            daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
            nextMonth = 1;
            Log.d(tag, "**--> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                    + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                    + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
        } else {
            prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
            nextMonth = currentMonth + 1;
            nextYear = yy;
            prevYear = yy;
            daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
            Log.d(tag, "***---> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                    + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                    + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
        }

        int currentWeekDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
        trailingSpaces = currentWeekDay;

        Log.d(tag, "Week Day:" + currentWeekDay + " is "
                + getWeekDayAsString(currentWeekDay));
        Log.d(tag, "No. Trailing space to Add: " + trailingSpaces);
        Log.d(tag, "No. of Days in Previous Month: " + daysInPrevMonth);

        if (cal.isLeapYear(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)))
            if (mm == 2)
                ++daysInMonth;
            else if (mm == 3)
                ++daysInPrevMonth;

        // Trailing Month days
        for (int i = 0; i < trailingSpaces; i++) {
            Log.d(tag,
                    "PREV MONTH:= "
                            + prevMonth

                                + " => "
                            + 
    getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
                            + " "
                            + 
   String.valueOf((daysInPrevMonth
                                    - 
   trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
                                    + i));
            list.add(String
                    .valueOf((daysInPrevMonth - trailingSpaces 
  + DAY_OFFSET)
                            + i)
                    + "-GREY"
                    + "-"
                    + getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
                    + "-"
                    + prevYear);
        }

        // Current Month Days
        for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
            Log.d(currentMonthName, String.valueOf(i) + " "
                    + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + " " + 
   yy);
            if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth()) {
                list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-"
                        + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + 
    "-" + yy);
            } else {
                list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-"
                        + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + 
     "-" + yy);
            }
        }

        // Leading Month days
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size() % 7; i++) {
            Log.d(tag, "NEXT MONTH:= " + getMonthAsString(nextMonth));
            list.add(String.valueOf(i + 1) + "-GREY" + "-"
                    + getMonthAsString(nextMonth) + "-" + 
      nextYear);
        }
    }

    /**
     * NOTE: YOU NEED TO IMPLEMENT THIS PART Given the YEAR, MONTH, retrieve
     * ALL entries from a SQLite database for that month. Iterate over the
     * List of All entries, and get the dateCreated, which is converted into
     * day.
     * 
     * @param year
     * @param month
     * @return
     */
    private HashMap<String, Integer> findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(int year,
            int month) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context

 .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_gridcell, parent, 
 false);
        }

        // Get a reference to the Day gridcell
        gridcell = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.calendar_day_gridcell);
        gridcell.setOnClickListener(this);

        // ACCOUNT FOR SPACING

        Log.d(tag, "Current Day: " + getCurrentDayOfMonth());
        String[] day_color = list.get(position).split("-");
        String theday = day_color[0];
        String themonth = day_color[2];
        String theyear = day_color[3];
        if ((!eventsPerMonthMap.isEmpty()) && (eventsPerMonthMap != 
  null))    {
            if (eventsPerMonthMap.containsKey(theday)) {
                num_events_per_day = (TextView) row

.findViewById(R.id.num_events_per_day);
                Integer numEvents = (Integer) 
    eventsPerMonthMap.get(theday);
                num_events_per_day.setText(numEvents.toString());
            }
        }

        // Set the Day GridCell
        gridcell.setText(theday);
        gridcell.setTag(theday + "-" + themonth + "-" + theyear);
        Log.d(tag, "Setting GridCell " + theday + "-" + themonth + "-"
                + theyear);

        if (day_color[1].equals("GREY")) {
            gridcell.setTextColor(getResources()
                    .getColor(R.color.lightgray));
        }
        if (day_color[1].equals("WHITE")) {
            gridcell.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
                    R.color.lightgray02));
        }
        if (day_color[1].equals("BLUE")) {

   gridcell.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orrange));
        }
        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String date_month_year = (String) view.getTag();
        selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: " + date_month_year);
        Log.e("Selected date", date_month_year);
        try {
            Date parsedDate = dateFormatter.parse(date_month_year);
            Log.d(tag, "Parsed Date: " + parsedDate.toString());

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public int getCurrentDayOfMonth() {
        return currentDayOfMonth;
    }

    private void setCurrentDayOfMonth(int currentDayOfMonth) {
        this.currentDayOfMonth = currentDayOfMonth;
    }

    public void setCurrentWeekDay(int currentWeekDay) {
        this.currentWeekDay = currentWeekDay;
    }

    public int getCurrentWeekDay() {
        return currentWeekDay;
    }
}
 }



    public class HorizontalListView extends AdapterView<ListAdapter> {

public boolean mAlwaysOverrideTouch = true;
protected ListAdapter mAdapter;
private int mLeftViewIndex = -1;
private int mRightViewIndex = 0;
protected int mCurrentX;
protected int mNextX;
private int mMaxX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
private int mDisplayOffset = 0;
protected Scroller mScroller;
private GestureDetector mGesture;
private Queue<View> mRemovedViewQueue = new LinkedList<View>();
private OnItemSelectedListener mOnItemSelected;
private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClicked;
private OnItemLongClickListener mOnItemLongClicked;
private boolean mDataChanged = false;


public HorizontalListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initView();
}

private synchronized void initView() {
    mLeftViewIndex = -1;
    mRightViewIndex = 0;
    mDisplayOffset = 0;
    mCurrentX = 0;
    mNextX = 0;
    mMaxX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    mScroller = new Scroller(getContext());
    mGesture = new GestureDetector(getContext(), mOnGesture);
}

@Override
public void setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener 
   listener)   {
    mOnItemSelected = listener;
}

@Override
public void setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener){
    mOnItemClicked = listener;
}

@Override
public void setOnItemLongClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener  
   listener) {
    mOnItemLongClicked = listener;
}

private DataSetObserver mDataObserver = new DataSetObserver() {

    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        synchronized(HorizontalListView.this){
            mDataChanged = true;
        }
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInvalidated() {
        reset();
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }

};

@Override
public ListAdapter getAdapter() {
    return mAdapter;
}

@Override
public View getSelectedView() {
    //TODO: implement
    return null;
}

@Override
public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    if(mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataObserver);
    }
    mAdapter = adapter;
    mAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(mDataObserver);
    reset();
}

private synchronized void reset(){
    initView();
    removeAllViewsInLayout();
    requestLayout();
}

@Override
public void setSelection(int position) {
    //TODO: implement
}

private void addAndMeasureChild(final View child, int viewPos) {
    LayoutParams params = child.getLayoutParams();
    if(params == null) {
        params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  
   LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    }

    addViewInLayout(child, viewPos, params, true);
    child.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getHeight(), 
   MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
}



@Override
protected synchronized void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int 
  right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    if(mAdapter == null){
        return;
    }

    if(mDataChanged){
        int oldCurrentX = mCurrentX;
        initView();
        removeAllViewsInLayout();
        mNextX = oldCurrentX;
        mDataChanged = false;
    }

    if(mScroller.computeScrollOffset()){
        int scrollx = mScroller.getCurrX();
        mNextX = scrollx;
    }

    if(mNextX <= 0){
        mNextX = 0;
        mScroller.forceFinished(true);
    }
    if(mNextX >= mMaxX) {
        mNextX = mMaxX;
        mScroller.forceFinished(true);
    }

    int dx = mCurrentX - mNextX;

    removeNonVisibleItems(dx);
    fillList(dx);
    positionItems(dx);

    mCurrentX = mNextX;

    if(!mScroller.isFinished()){
        post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                requestLayout();
            }
        });

    }
}

private void fillList(final int dx) {
    int edge = 0;
    View child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    if(child != null) {
        edge = child.getRight();
    }
    fillListRight(edge, dx);

    edge = 0;
    child = getChildAt(0);
    if(child != null) {
        edge = child.getLeft();
    }
    fillListLeft(edge, dx);


}

private void fillListRight(int rightEdge, final int dx) {
    while(rightEdge + dx < getWidth() && mRightViewIndex < 
  mAdapter.getCount()) {

        View child = mAdapter.getView(mRightViewIndex, 
      mRemovedViewQueue.poll(), this);
        addAndMeasureChild(child, -1);
        rightEdge += child.getMeasuredWidth();

        if(mRightViewIndex == mAdapter.getCount()-1) {
            mMaxX = mCurrentX + rightEdge - getWidth();
        }

        if (mMaxX < 0) {
            mMaxX = 0;
        }
        mRightViewIndex++;
    }

}

private void fillListLeft(int leftEdge, final int dx) {
    while(leftEdge + dx > 0 && mLeftViewIndex >= 0) {
        View child = mAdapter.getView(mLeftViewIndex, 
    mRemovedViewQueue.poll(), this);
        addAndMeasureChild(child, 0);
        leftEdge -= child.getMeasuredWidth();
        mLeftViewIndex--;
        mDisplayOffset -= child.getMeasuredWidth();
    }
}

private void removeNonVisibleItems(final int dx) {
    View child = getChildAt(0);
    while(child != null && child.getRight() + dx <= 0) {
        mDisplayOffset += child.getMeasuredWidth();
        mRemovedViewQueue.offer(child);
        removeViewInLayout(child);
        mLeftViewIndex++;
        child = getChildAt(0);

    }

    child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    while(child != null && child.getLeft() + dx >= getWidth()) {
        mRemovedViewQueue.offer(child);
        removeViewInLayout(child);
        mRightViewIndex--;
        child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    }
}

private void positionItems(final int dx) {
    if(getChildCount() > 0){
        mDisplayOffset += dx;
        int left = mDisplayOffset;
        for(int i=0;i<getChildCount();i++){
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
            child.layout(left, 0, left + childWidth, 
    child.getMeasuredHeight());
            left += childWidth + child.getPaddingRight();
        }
    }
}

public synchronized void scrollTo(int x) {
    mScroller.startScroll(mNextX, 0, x - mNextX, 0);
    requestLayout();
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    boolean handled = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    handled |= mGesture.onTouchEvent(ev);
    return handled;
}

protected boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
    synchronized(HorizontalListView.this){
        mScroller.fling(mNextX, 0, (int)-velocityX, 0, 0, mMaxX, 0, 0);
    }
    requestLayout();

    return true;
}

protected boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    mScroller.forceFinished(true);
    return true;
}

private OnGestureListener mOnGesture = new 
  GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return HorizontalListView.this.onDown(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        return HorizontalListView.this.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, 
    velocityY);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
            float distanceX, float distanceY) {

        synchronized(HorizontalListView.this){
            mNextX += (int)distanceX;
        }
        requestLayout();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        for(int i=0;i<getChildCount();i++){
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (isEventWithinView(e, child)) {
                if(mOnItemClicked != null){

 mOnItemClicked.onItemClick(HorizontalListView.this, child, mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i, 
 mAdapter.getItemId( mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i ));
                }
                if(mOnItemSelected != null){

mOnItemSelected.onItemSelected(HorizontalListView.this, child, mLeftViewIndex + 1 + 
 i,    mAdapter.getItemId( mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i ));
                }
                break;
            }

        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (isEventWithinView(e, child)) {
                if (mOnItemLongClicked != null) {

 mOnItemLongClicked.onItemLongClick(HorizontalListView.this, child, mLeftViewIndex + 
 1   +    i, mAdapter.getItemId(mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i));
                }
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    private boolean isEventWithinView(MotionEvent e, View child) {
        Rect viewRect = new Rect();
        int[] childPosition = new int[2];
        child.getLocationOnScreen(childPosition);
        int left = childPosition[0];
        int right = left + child.getWidth();
        int top = childPosition[1];
        int bottom = top + child.getHeight();
        viewRect.set(left, top, right, bottom);
        return viewRect.contains((int) e.getRawX(), (int) e.getRawY());
    }
};



       }
```

Comment: i follow this tutorial for horizontal listview  http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34   problem is curent date is not focus in list

Comment: how many items are you displaying in the horizontal view ???